# Unable to access entity framework entities in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have added an EF test.edmx in App_Code folder. Model is generated from database.

Then i have added a class in App_Code folder by the name of "clsUser". Now if i am trying to access this clsUser class in some webform i am not able to locate it. To solve this problem i had set the build action of class as compile but now when i am trying to access entities generated by ef in the clsuser class it is not able to find it.

clsUser.cs

```
   public User Authenicate(int AccountNumber, string password)
        {
            testEntities db = new testEntities();
            User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.account_number == AccountNumber && u.password == password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                Load(user);
                return user;
            }
            else return null;
        }
```

it is not able to identify the return type of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the VS 2012. I updated some packages using Nuget and it started causing problems. I ended up re installing VS to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what exact `Entities` are you expecting by adding a project reference and a using directive to location where `Entities` are located

Comment: but i am not able to create object in statement "testEntities db = new testEntities();"

if build action is content then it gives no error(except i am not able to create its object webform) if build action is compile then no error in webform but not able to create object of entity.

Comment: do you have a reference and an using directive in `clsUser` to the project where your context is located?

Comment: i am not able to locate context also if build action is Compile.

Comment: that I do understand. but are you having a reference to the project where context is and a using directive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54193/discussion-between-andrew-and-deep-sharma).